# How to test the laravel Mailer using Phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-7

I need to test the Laravel Mailer using PHPunit, I am using `CRUD` Operations, where if any one the method fails, It should trigger the mail. I need to test the mail part, below is the code.

```
 public function index()
    {
       
        $response = Http::withBasicAuth(userName,passWord)
            ->get(connection());
        $this->html_mail($response);
        return $response->json();
    }
```

```
 public function show($id)
    {
      $response = Http::withBasicAuth(userName, passWord)
            ->get(connection());
        // check response & send mail if error
        $this->html_mail($response);
        $record = collect($response->json() ['output'])
            ->where($this->primaryKeyname, $id)->first();
        return $record;
    }
```

Mailer method:

```
 public function html_mail($response)
    {
        if ($response->failed() || $response->serverError() || $response->clientError()) {
            Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($response) {
                $message->to('foo@example.com');
                $message->subject('Sample test');
                $message->setBody($response, 'text/html');
            });
        }

        return 'Mail Sent Successfully';
    }
}
```

Could someone please help to test the Mailer method  using PHPunit.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be some code missing in your examples, but generally you're looking for [Laravel's `Mail::fake()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#mail-fake):

```php
# tests/Feature/YourControllerTest.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

/**
 * @test
 */
public function index_should_send_an_email_if_authentication_fails(): void
{
    Mail::fake();

    $this->withToken('invalidToken', 'Basic')
        ->get('your.route.name');

    Mail::assertSent(function ($mail) {
        // Make any assertions you need to in here.
        return $mail->hasTo('foo@example.com');
    });
}
```

There's also an opportunity to clean up your controller methods here by [leveraging middleware for authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#http-basic-authentication) rather than repeating it in every method.

Digging into `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard`, Laravel automaticallys fire an `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed` event if authentication fails. Instead of sending directly from your controller, you might consider [registering an event listener](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events#registering-events-and-listeners) and attaching it to that event, then letting the listener [dispatch a mailable notification](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications).

```php
# app/Providers/EventServiceProvider

/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed' => [
        'App\\Listeners\\FailedAuthAttempt',
    ],
];
```

With those changes, your testing also becomes easier:

```php
# tests/Feature/Notifications/FailedAuthAttemptTest.php

use App\Notifications\FailedAuthAttempt;
use Illuminate\Notifications\AnonymousNotifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

/**
 * @test
 */
public function it_should_send_an_email_upon_authentication_failure(): void
{
    Notification::fake();

    $this->withToken('invalidToken', 'Basic')
        ->get('your.route.name');

    Notification::assertSentTo(new AnonymousNotifiable(), FailedAuthAttempt::class);
}
```

Now, any route in your application that uses Laravel's `auth.basic` middleware will automatically send the `FailedAuthAttempt` notification upon failure. This also makes it easier to, for example, [send these notices to a Slack channel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#specifying-delivery-channels) rather than sending emails.